# Class Decorator Compatible for Mypy

Tags: python, decorator, type-hinting, mypy, class-decorator

Say I have the following simple example without any typehints:

```py
def wrapper(cls):
    class Subclass(cls):
        def subclass_method(self):
            pass
    return Subclass


@wrapper
class Parent:
    def parent_method(self):
        pass


p = Parent()
p.parent_method()
p.subclass_method()
```

How can I restructure this code using typehints, such that when I run `mypy` against an instance of `Parent`, it will recognize both `subclass_method` and `parent_method`?

Possible solutions:

- **Using a mixin `Parent(Mixin)`**: Works, but avoids the decorator. Is it possible to achieve without?
- **Patching the method onto the existing class**: Still has the same issue of resolving `subclass_method` in mypy
- **Custom Mypy plugin**: Wouldn't be sure where to start with this one, or if it would be possible without one.

Comment: Have you tried something like `def wrapper(cls) -> Callable[[...], "Subclass"]:`. Maybe you'd have to move the class definition outside the decorator.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yeah that's kind of what I'm thinking, but I imagine `Subclass` would have to extend some `Generic[T]` to then have `parent_method` still be validated. I'm thinking this might require some sort of stub `.pyi` file.

Comment: What's the real-world use case for such a wrapper? Seems more complicated than defining `Subclass` *once* as a mix-in and using (multiple) inheritance directly.

Comment: Every class you decorate has a *different* class providing `subclass_method`, making your class hierarchy unnecessarily bloated.

Comment: @chepner I'm using the `dataclasses-json` library from pypi, and they provide a decorator `@dataclass_json` which adds some methods to the class methods for decoding/ encoding to json. The annoying part is that these methods do not show up in mypy. I agree the mixin approach is probably the easiest solution, but for curiosity sake, I would like to see how this might be achieved using the decorator.

Comment: Once [Intersection](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) gets implemented, you could move the mixin class to the global scope and then use the type hint `Intersection[T, SomeMixin]`. At the moment that's not possible though.

Comment: @a_guest Yeah I was looking at that open issue. It seems like it could be the missing piece here!

Answer (score 2):

This would be much simpler without the wrapper at all.

```
class SomeMixin:
    def subclass_method(self):
        pass


class Parent(SomeMixin):
    def parent_method(self):
        pass


p = Parent()
p.parent_method()
p.subclass_method()
```

Here, you define `SomeMixin` *once*, not once per call to a wrapper, and the class `SomeMixin` is known statically. All the various classes with the name `Subclass` are created *dynamically*, and `mypy` can't know *statically* which class the name `Parent` is actually bound to.

Comment: I think this is a good compromise, but I would still like to see if the decorator approach is possible! At the end of the day, I'd just like to see `@wrapper class Parent: pass` be able to resolve the `subclass_method` method.

Comment: The decorator approach is fundamentally at odds with `mypy`. `mypy` checks *static* typing, while the decorator makes *dynamic* changes to the type of the value bound to `Parent`.

Comment: If you really want to use a decorator, I would suggest writing one that adds a new method *directly* to the decorated class, rather than creating a new class at run-time via inheritance.

Comment: I find that a little bit surprising seeing as `@dataclass` is supported, but perhaps that is fairly special-cased in mypy?

Comment: `dataclass` doesn't change the static type. It heavily patches the original class rather than creating a new class that inherits from the original class (which is along the lines of what I was suggesting when you mentioned `dataclass`).

Comment: Interesting, so if using the decorator, patching is probably the way to go. But wouldn't those patched methods also be dynamically set? Shouldn't it have the same issue for resolving the extra methods?

Comment: I don't know exactly how `mypy` does its thing; it may be statically simulating the MRO, which `dataclass` doesn't change but your decorator does.

Comment: I agree with you, and the mixin approach is what I'm currently using from dataclasses-json to satisfy mypy: https://lidatong.github.io/dataclasses-json/#approach-2-inherit-from-a-mixin I do see that mypy supports custom plugins, which may be where this question is leaning.

Comment: this answer doesn't address the issue when decorators have to be used, *and* they are coming from an external package/library.